# Перестановка строк и столбцов в матрице для перемещения влево вверх. (С)

Tags: c++, c

Необходимо двигать строки и столбцы так, чтобы наибольший элемент оказался слева вверху. До того, как начал разбираться с этими перемещениями, все работало. И вот в части кода с перемещениями (два цикла в конце), появляется такая ошибка: `expression must have pointer-to-object`. Не совсем понятно, как правильно сделать перемещение строк и столбцов? Помогите, пожалуйста

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main()
{
    int *a;  // указатель на массив
    int i, j, n, m, line, column, imax, jmax;
    printf("write the quantity of the lines\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    printf("write the quantity of the columns\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &m);
    printf("\n it would be matrix %dx%d\n", n, m);
    // Выделение памяти
    a = (int*)malloc(n*m * sizeof(int));
    // Ввод элементов массива
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)  // цикл по строкам
    {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)  // цикл по столбцам
        {
            printf("\na[%d][%d] =", i, j);
            scanf_s("%d", (a + i * m + j)); // обращение к элементу с использованием указателя; a - указатель на массив 
        }
    }
    // Вывод элементов массива
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)  // цикл по строкам
    {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)  // цикл по столбцам
        {
            printf("%5d ", *(a + i * m + j)); // 5 знакомест под элемент массива
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    int max = a[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)//Нахождение максимального элемента и его положения
    {
            for (int j = 1; j < m; j++)
            {
                if (a[i] > max)
                {
                    max = a[i];
                    imax = i;
                    jmax = j;
                }

            }
    }
    printf("the biggest element of the array is %d", max);

    for (int i = 0, temp = 0; i < n; i++) //imax, jmax - строки и столбца максимального элемента, n -кол-во строк
    {
        temp = a[0][i];
        a[0][i] = a[imax][i];
        a[imax][i] = temp;
    }

    for (int i = 0, temp = 0; i < m; i++) // перестановка столбца, m -кол-во столбцов
    {

        temp = a[i][0];
        a[i][0] = a[i][jmax];
        a[i][jmax] = temp;
    }





    free(a);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Необходимо двигать строки и столбцы так, чтобы наибольший элемент оказался слева вверху. До того, как начал разбираться с этими перемещениями, все работало. И вот в части кода с перемещениями (два цикла в конце), появляется такая ошибка: expression must have pointer-to-object. Не совсем понятно, как правильно сделать перемещение строк и столбцов? Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: @amiranys вот вопрос, долго писал его просто.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем коде `a` имеет тип `int*`. `a[i][j]` - будет эквивалентно `*(*(a + i) + j)`. Т.е. вы пытаетесь разыменовать `int*` дважды. `*(a + i)` в результате даст `int`, затем вы прибавляете `j` и применяете унарный `*` к `int`-у, что разумеется недопустимо.

Вы можете использовать тот подход, который был использован выше в вашем коде: заменить `a[i][j]` на `a[i * m + j]`.

Другой подход состоит в том, чтобы использовать более похожую на двумерный массив сущность - массив указателей на массивы.

```
int row = 5;
int col = 4;
int ** matrix = malloc(sizeof(int*) * row);
for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i)
{
    matrix[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * col);
}
```

При таком подходе можно будет использовать `a[i][j]` для доступа к элементу на `i`-той строке, `j`-том столбце.
Очищать динамическую память, выделенную таким образом необходимо зеркально:

```
for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i)
{
    free(matrix[i]);
}
free(matrix);
```

Также пересмотрите логику алгоритма, в частности алгоритм нахождения максимума.